# Mock IHttpContextAccessor in Integration Tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core

I would like to test one method in controller which is retrieving value from `IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress`.

Is it possible to customize [WebApplicationFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-5.0#aspnet-core-integration-tests) so one can set fixed ip address?

The workaround would be to wrap the expression above into service so it can be mocked.

Thanks

*Test.cs*

```cs
var ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.123");
var factory = new WebApplicationFactory<Startup>();
// ?

using var client = factory.CreateClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("https://localhost/test"), UriKind.Relative));
var ipAddress = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

*TestController.cs*

```
  private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

  public TestController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {

            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

  [HttpGet("test")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> GetTest()
  {

      var ipAddressObj = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;

      var ipAddress = ipAddressObj?.ToString();

      return Ok(ipAddress);
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Moq;
using System.Net;
using WebApplication.Api.Controllers;
using Xunit;

namespace WebApplication.Api.Tests
{
    public class TestControllerTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public async void IpAdressResult()
        {
            var ipAddress = "192.168.1.123";
            var accessorMcok = new Mock<IHttpContextAccessor>();
            accessorMcok.Setup(a => a.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress).Returns(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress));

            var controller = new TestController(accessorMcok.Object);

            var result = (OkObjectResult)(await controller.GetTest());
            Assert.Equal(ipAddress, result.Value);
        }
    }
}
```